# Questions about in-world legality and ethicality are primarily opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, canon, primarily-opinion-based

The legal governance of any reality, and the ethical concepts of that reality, I do not believe are a matter of opinion. Pedantically, you can say how we "out here" (the audience) feel about the ethics in a story are opinions but that is not what was asked.

Asking for canon governance on use of [Tribbles as weapons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220735/what-governs-tribble-weapons) has been ruled "opinion-based" by FIVE separate people. How so?

Comment: You didn't ask whether it was legal, you asked whether it met the definition of legal *as defined by a fanfic rule*

Comment: Untrue. I provided the best research I could locate, which happened to be fanfic rule. I clearly stated the credibility of the lead was suspect. How did you think I wanted anything defined? That question would be "Is GO-19 Star Trek Canon?" I already answered that it is not.

Comment: Removing it entirely would probably bring the question on-topic. I doubt it's answerable, but at least it would get reopened.

Comment: I was only trying to narrow the search down, maybe someone had a credible source. OK.

Comment: I've done an edit to suggest what sort of changes would be likely to get it reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that the problem here is your (extensive) mention of General Order 19, a fan-fiction creation from the ST-Minutiae website. It seems like you're asking people to agree or disagree with a rule that was conceived **outside of the Star Trek canon**, which typically includes the films and TV shows.

I can see things from your perspective. You didn't actually ask whether this rule was canon or not, but you need to be aware that simply *including it* in the question changes the focus dramatically. Better to remove it, refocus the question and try to pose your challenge more directly.

I've done an edit to suggest a way of resolving the question a little more closely. I would imagine that this would also result in an upswing in votes. Obviously you're free to accept my suggestion or rollback as you see fit.